# Start reading file from a specific line

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I need to store all the lines from a file inside a table, but I need to start reading it at a specific point. Here's the file example:

```
class Foo as
 attribute max : number
 def static show as
 count : number
 begin
 io.print(count)
 return count
 end
 attribute min : number
end
program
 var x : number
 var foo : Foo
 x = 20
 foo = new Foo
 foo.show(x)
end
```

I need to start reading in program and store everything below program in a table.

I have done this:

```
for line in io.lines(file) do
    table.insert(program.body, line);
end;
```

But this (of course) loops through the entire file. I need to loop from **program** to **end**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local inside
for line in io.lines(file) do
    inside = inside or line:match"^program"
    table.insert(program.body, inside and line);
end;
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what is happening in the "inside" variable? Thanks. :)

Comment: `inside` is `nil` before the line starting with "program" and is not `nil` after that line. ["and" in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html)